# Meaning of distinct walks in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a statement to prove that the union of any two distinct walks joining two points in a graph contains a cycle.

Does distinct walks here means there are no common lines in the two walks or does it mean there may be some overlapping lines but there exist some line which is present in one walk but not present in the other?

I think the second definition is correct because if there are no overlapping lines in two distinct walks then the result is trivially true and there is nothing to prove.

Thankyou for your responses in advance!

Comment: Yes, the second definition is the correct one. Hint: the cycle you are looking for need not include the two endpoints of the paths.

Comment: "Distinct" just means they're not both the same one. Or if there are more than two, it means no two of them are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The second interpretation is the only thing that "distinct" should mean.

However, in this specific context, it is:

1. Kind of stupid: if you have any $u-v$ walk, you can find another $u-v$ walk distinct from it just by walking back and forth along one of the edges. For example, if $(a,b,c)$ is an $a-c$ walk, then $(a,b,a,b,c)$ is another $a-c$ walk distinct from it.
2. Not enough to guarantee a cycle, because you can do the above even in trees, which don't contain any cycles.

So I would assume that the statement is intended to say that there are two **edge-disjoint** walks between a pair of vertices: they have no common edges.

(The result is still not trivial in this case, because combining the two walks may give a closed walk that isn't a cycle.)

Alternatively, as Jaap Scherphuis points out, we might suppose that there are two distinct **paths**, in which case the objection above also does not apply.

Comment: I think it was probably a question about two distinct **paths** rather than walks.

Comment: That's a good point. Either way, some word is not being used in the conventional meaning.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. I thought it is true and tried to prove it but in the question it was mentioned to either prove or disprove the statement!!!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov If the walks are edge disjoint as mentioned by you, then the whole union may not be a cycle but it will contain a cycle in it , I guess?